# Mapping nested form values to C# object

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I'm trying to take a form post and map it to an object that is a parameter of a controller, but I'm having trouble getting the nested values to map to the object.

My form data from the post (note, I only included the problem data):

```
draw: 1
columns[0][data]:Username
columns[0][name]:
columns[0][searchable]:true
columns[0][orderable]:true
columns[1][data]:FirstName
columns[1][name]:
columns[1][searchable]:true
columns[1][orderable]:true

...
```

I have classes  that looks like this:

```
public class Table
{
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public List<Column> columns { get; set; }     
}

public class Column
{
    public string data { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Boolean searchable { get; set; }
    public Boolean orderable { get; set; }
}
```

And my controller accepting the post:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult GetUsers(Table table);
```

The `columns` and the `draw` variables map just fine when I view it in my debugger, however the specific column data like `data` turn out to be `null`. I figured I just have my object not represented correctly to take this data. This form data is from the jquery plugin datatables, so it isn't very flexible on changing how the form data is formatted (to my knowledge at least, I'd love to know if it can be sent as json rather than this format).

Comment: I think you need this http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: The sequential ordering of the index (numbers) of your `columns[i]` matters. Also, the way your form is rendered in your .cshtml will matter. In order to pinpoint the issue, can you give as a look at your form (Html.BeginForm) code?